# Why this Java code do not write entire list on text file?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, file-io, selenium-webdriver

This java code prints text of all the webelements in console but when I write it on a text file, the output is a incomplete list. It do not write last 50-60 webelement text. What can be the reason ? 
(I am using this code in selenium webdriver and the browser is Firefox.)

```
    String TestFile = "D:\\temp.txt";
    File FC = new File(TestFile);
    FC.createNewFile();
    FileWriter FW = new FileWriter(TestFile);
    BufferedWriter BW = new BufferedWriter(FW);
    List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.className("someclassname"));
    for(WebElement ele : elementList){
        System.out.println(ele.getText());
        BW.write(ele.getText()); 
        BW.newLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close() the `BW` so the end of the text was left in the buffer.

Add to the end of this code

```
BW.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, It was one of the silliest mistake.